# Monotouch thrown an unhandled exception trying to deploy app for second times

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.ios

I create a project for iOS with `xamarin studio 2`.
First time I debug it in `VS2010 profession` , it run correctly. 
Then I stop debugging and restart debug again, I got an exception.

```
 Exception: Unhandled Exception (Generic) There was an unhandled exception trying to deploy and run your application.System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.Dispose()

 at Mono.IOS.VisualStudio.MonoTouchFlavoredProject.StopDebug()

 at Mono.IOS.VisualStudio.MonoTouchFlavoredProject.DebugApplication(MonoTouchDevice device, IVsOutputWindowPane output)

 at Mono.IOS.VisualStudio.MonoTouchFlavoredProject.DebugLaunch(__VSDBGLAUNCHFLAGS grfLaunch)
```

If I close `VS` and restart `VS` debug again, it works. But I don't want to restart `VS` again and again. Anyone can help?

My **Xcode** is `4.6.` **iOS SDK** is `6.1`
**Xamarin Studio** for **Mac** is `4.0(build 2003)`

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XATHQ.png)

Comment: I'm sitting with the same problem... Have you managed to get past this?

Comment: xamarin need to run on mac os to build iOS App